# Supremum of set $A=\left\{1+\frac{1}{n}: n \in \mathbb{N} \right\}$

Tags: real-analysis

I am having a bit of trouble finding the supremum here. usually, it is just a matter of finding the sequence, but I can't even find that here. It also does not appear that there is even a global maximum here to find the upper bound? What am I missing?

Comment: Are any element greater than $2$?

Comment: No...so the supreme is just 2? Whats the sequence that yields a limit of 2?

Comment: Aargh! "supreme" is even worse than "suprema"! If you don't want to say "least upper bound", the word is "supremum".

Comment: @AggrawalPuja are there lesser upper bound?

Comment: Typo! Unforunately!

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$1+\frac{1}{n}$ is a decreasing sequence.

The first few terms are $2,1.5,1+\frac13,1+\frac14,\ldots$

Can you spot the biggest element?

Edit after reading comment:

a sequence $a_n \in A$ that converges to $2$ is $2,2,2,2,\ldots$.

Comment: So the series converges down ...I see that. But the suprema is just 2 then? It was just hard to spot the pattern here.

Comment: Yes. the answer is just $2$. Since $2$ is the first term and the sequence decreases, $2$ is an upper bound. Any number that is smaller than $2$ would not be an upper bound of $2$. hence $2$ is the least upper bound.